# Zend OPcache and HHVM both together

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, hhvm, opcache

*My environment is:*

- Ubuntu 14.04
- PHP 5.5
- nginx 1.7.6

> PHP 5.5.19-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) (built: Nov 19 2014 19:33:43)
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright
>   (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev,
>   Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies

I want to use both Zend OpCache and HHVM together, is this allowed ? Will I get better performance with this option?

Comment: I use HHVM for webpages and PHP 5.6 + opcache for Cronjobs.

Comment: [flowl blog article "HHVM with OpCache"](https://blog.flowl.info/2015/hhvm-with-opcache/)

Answer (score 3):

This is not required - HHVM effectively replaces PHP altogether.

Comment: so is there any problem if i enable zendopcache when running with hhvm

Comment: You mean in the `/etc/php.d/' config file for the Zend OpCode cache? No, no problem, because HHVM won't refer to anything inside of that directory for configuration. That Zend config will only come into effect when PHP cli, mod_php etc is used.